# Displaying only date from DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am trying to display only the date of the datetime property and the price of a decimal property formated in curency.But I must be doing something wrong because the formating does not work.This is how it is displayed:

[image]

I would like this to only display the date and the price using curency dolar amount.
This is my models code:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:c}")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

And this is the code that I used for the view:

```
         <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PublicationDate , "Publication Date")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PublicationDate, new { @class = "datepicker"})
         </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price)
         </p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the DataFormat anotations can not be applied to TextBoxFor and LabelFor they can only be applied to DisplayFor and EditorFor

Answer (score 4):

[DateTime Formats](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) for Date

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
```

[Double Formats](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) for Currency

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:0.00}")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have tryed this solutiong it is actualy the first one I have tryed even before posting here and it works but not for this page for some reason...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an MVC person, but I suspect you just want a DisplayFormatString:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:d}")]
```

`d` is a [standard date/time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for "short date". You could also use a [custom date/time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). Note that for text being displayed to a user, a standard date/time format is usually better as it can adjust for a user's culture appropriately. If you use a fixed custom format such as "MM/dd/yyyy" or "dd/MM/yyyy" then you'll end up confusing users who use different formats. (For example, "06/05/2013" is May 6th in the UK, but June 5th in the US.)

If you need this for *input* though, you'd probably be best off with a date picker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formatting string `"{0:d}"` for the short date-only pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign it as>

```
DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

Or in case of datetimepicker>

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

There is also option called Format in case of datetime picker keep it as short.